# custom leftbarbuttonItem not showed in ios 11

Tags: objective-c, swift, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

i had a problem with a custom LeftBarButtonItem when i clicked for the first time it showed the custom leftbarbutton but in the second time it's hidden !!!! this problem appear only in the ios 11 but in ios10 it's worked perfectly.

```
Class A:
- (void)setBackButton {
    if (_backTabBarItem == nil) {
        UIButton *backButton     = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        [backButton setImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"icon_back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor white] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    }
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:_backTabBarItem animated:NO];
}
```

in class B:

```
func showLisHikeViewController(actionView: ActionView) {
        let listHikeController = EMListHikeViewController.sharedManager() as! EMListHikeViewController

        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"ic_slide"),style : .plain, target: self, action: #selector(EMSlideMenu.leftButtonAction)) //Use a selector
        listHikeController.backTabBarItem = leftButton
.....
}
```

Any help please